# Is it possible in XPath to find parent when none of the children met some criteria

Tags: xml, xpath

I want to find parents when none of the children met some criteria, for example find those **section** that has no **item** in its sub-level. Is it possible with XPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `//section[not(item)]` finds all `section` elements not having any `item` child elements or `//section[not(descendant::item)]` finds all `section` elements not having any descendant `item` elements.
Is that what you are looking for? If not then consider to show an XML input sample and a more detailed explanation of what elements you are looking for.