# XPath to find parent of children nodes with certain names in ColdFusion-8

Tags: xml, xpath, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Using Coldfusion 8 and XMLSearch() I am trying to build a XPath() statment that will find the occurance of specific children of a parent.

I have parents `combinationCharts`  who can have children of `bar` or `line` or both.  I need to be able to find the three combinations of `bar no line`; `line no bar`; or `bar and line`  I've tried several iterations of

```
<cfset myBarLineChart = XMLSearch(cleanedXML, "//*[descendant::combinationChartTypes][contains(name(),'bar') and contains(name(),'line')]" )>
```

Using different combinations of `descendant` or `child` or `//*` etc.  Somehow, I just can't find the magic order to get any results.

The ones that work are:

```
<cfset myBarChart = XMLSearch(cleanedXML, "//*[name()='combinationChartTypes']//*[name()='bar']")>  

<cfset myLineChart = XMLSearch(cleanedXML, "//*[name()='combinationChartTypes']//*[name()='line']")>
```

But the problem is they double count when a `combinationChartTypes` has both `bar` and `line`

I've tried solutions from:

[Recursive Query of XML in ColdFusion 8 to find unknown number of children sub levels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28370017/recursive-query-of-xml-in-coldfusion-8-to-find-unknown-number-of-children-sub-le)

[Is it possible in XPath to find parent when none of the children met some criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10040787/is-it-possible-in-xpath-to-find-parent-when-none-of-the-children-met-some-criter)

All to no avail, even after reading and re-reading over:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp

http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html#Pages~List_of_XPaths

Any help to point me in the right direction or to solve this outright would be much appreciated!

Here is the sample xml that I'm searching over:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<report expressionlocale="en" ignorefiltercontext="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><reportName>Revenue by GO Subsidiary 2005</reportName>
...
<!--- Example of line chart only --->
<combinationChartTypes>
    <line bordercolor="black" datapointsize="4" pointchartdatapointshape="verticalLine" showabsolutevalues="true" showborders="false" showline="false" showvalues="false" usenumericalaxis="numericalAxisY1" valuetype="absolute">
        <chartNodes>
            <chartNode>
                <chartNodeMembers>
                    <chartNodeMember refdataitem="Example of line chart only">
                        <chartContents>
                            <chartTextItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                </dataSource>
                            </chartTextItem>
                        </chartContents>
                    </chartNodeMember>
                </chartNodeMembers>
            </chartNode>
        </chartNodes>
    </line>
</combinationChartTypes>
...
<!--- Example of bar chart only --->
...
<combinationChartTypes>
    <bar>
        <chartNodes>
            <chartNode>
                <chartNodeMembers>
                    <chartNodeMember refdataitem="Example of bar chart only">
                        <chartContents>
                            <chartTextItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                </dataSource>
                                    <conditionalDataSources refvariable="Report Language1">
                                    <conditionalDataSource refvariablevalue="de">
                                        <staticValue>Einnahmen (Millionen)</staticValue>
                                    </conditionalDataSource>
                                    <conditionalDataSource refvariablevalue="fr">
                                        <staticValue>Revenus (millions)</staticValue>
                                    </conditionalDataSource>
                            </chartTextItem>
                        </chartContents>
                    </chartNodeMember>
                </chartNodeMembers>
            </chartNode>
        </chartNodes>
    </bar>
</combinationChartTypes>
...
<!--- Example of bar and line chart mixed --->
...
<combinationChartTypes>
    <bar>
        <chartNodes>
            <chartNode>
                <chartNodeMembers>
                    <chartNodeMember refdataitem="example of bar and line chart mixed">
                        <chartContents>
                            <chartTextItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                </dataSource>
                                    <conditionalDataSources refvariable="Report Language1">
                                    <conditionalDataSource refvariablevalue="de">
                                        <staticValue>Einnahmen (Millionen)</staticValue>
                                    </conditionalDataSource>
                                    <conditionalDataSource refvariablevalue="fr">
                                        <staticValue>Revenus (millions)</staticValue>
                                    </conditionalDataSource>
                            </chartTextItem>
                        </chartContents>
                    </chartNodeMember>
                </chartNodeMembers>
            </chartNode>
        </chartNodes>
    </bar>
    <line bordercolor="black" datapointsize="4" pointchartdatapointshape="verticalLine" showabsolutevalues="true" showborders="false" showline="false" showvalues="false" usenumericalaxis="numericalAxisY1" valuetype="absolute">
        <chartNodes>
            <chartNode>
                <chartNodeMembers>
                    <chartNodeMember refdataitem="Same quarter, 2004">
                        <chartContents>
                            <chartTextItem>
                                <dataSource>
                                </dataSource>
                            </chartTextItem>
                        </chartContents>
                    </chartNodeMember>
                </chartNodeMembers>
            </chartNode>
        </chartNodes>
    </line>
</combinationChartTypes>
...
</report>
```

If you want the full long-ugly form of the file that is being searched it is here: http://jsfiddle.net/asheppardwork/3uuaj5jb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the default namespace (`xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`). (The fact that your XML is in the XHTML namespace without *actually* being XHTML is rather suspicious. I assume its creation process is broken. If you any influence on that, I suggest you start there.)

During standard XPath 1.0 use, searching for `//combinationChartTypes` will only turn up `<combinationChartTypes>` nodes **that are in no namespace**.

But you don't have any of those.

Now usually you would *register* the namespace URIs you need before you can use them in XPath, but ColdFusion 8 does not provide a way to do that. (If it would, you could register `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` as `xhtml` and then query for `"//xhtml:combinationChartTypes"`.)

---

`XmlSearch()` automagically supports namespace prefixes that are in the XML source:

```
<doc xmlns:foo="http://foo">
  <foo:element />
</doc>
```

and

```
<cfset result = XmlSearch(doc, "//foo:element")>
```

will return something. However, this is not the case for XML with a default namespace (i.e., no prefix).

In that case you can still fall back to this much more cumbersome pattern:

```
<cfset path = "//*[local-name() = 'combinationChartTypes' and *[local-name() = 'bar'] and not(*[local-name() = 'line'])]">
<cfset myBarChart = XMLSearch(cleanedXML, path)>
```

or, as a dirty hack, you *could* get away with `XmlParse(Replace(xml, 'xmlns="namespace-uri-in-question"', ''))` and then use `XmlSearch()` normally on the now namespace-less XML.

Comment: isn't that default namespace on line 2 of my sample? `<report expressionlocale="en" ignorefiltercontext="false" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` - either way, I'll try your suggestions, I didn't think of setting the path to a variable first, thanks.

Comment: Setting the path to a variable first has no influence on the result. I did it to prevent horizontal scrolling in the code sample. The XML default namespace does not affect XPath (i.e. it does not become the "XPath default namespace"). You *still* have to register and explicitly use it in any XPath you write (which, regrettably, ColdFusion does not support).

Comment: no joy. I tried   ```<cfset path = "//*:combinationChartTypes[bar and not(line)]">```  ```<cfset myBarLineChart = XMLSearch(cleanedXML, path)>```  and got the error: **An error occured while Searching an XML document.  Extra illegal tokens: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml', ':', 'combinationChartTypes', '[', 'bar', 'and', 'not', '(', 'line', ')', ']'** @tomalak

Comment: Impossible. The error message absolutely cannot contain the string `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` when your XPath does not contain that string. Make sure sure that the XML is well-formed first (test with `XmlParse()`). *After that* try `XMLSearch(cleanedXML, "//*:combinationChartTypes")`.

Comment: you're a pro!  The second more cumbersome pattern worked like a charm!  thanks much man!. I approved and upvoted the answer.

Comment: The reason for the strange results is because the frankenstein-ish nature of the xml.  Its not really true xml but the garbage produced by Cognos (ibm product); I put it through a "cleaning" process recommended by ben nadel (here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1723-parsing-invalid-html-into-xml-using-coldfusion-groovy-and-tagsoup.htm) By the time it comes out the other side it's just good enough for CF to let it through - I posted a jsfiddle link with what the ugliness looks like.  Thanks again man.

Comment: I'm not sure where I got this notion that `*:combinationChartTypes` was possible in ColdFusion. Maybe I remembered that wrong, I'll test this tomorrow. Nice to hear you got it working. The `local-name()` approach is a real pain. You *could* (extremely dirty hack) simply `Replace(xml, 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"', '')` and work with regular XPath.

Comment: @ASheppardWork Ahh, you copied that *entire* code from Ben Nadel's blog? Well, just remove the bit that sets the XHTML namespace, it's right there.